# I am getting an error while converting JSON to CSV using csvModule in WSO2 MI 410

Tags: json, csv, connector, wso2-micro-integrator

I am trying to convert JSON file to CSV file. I tried with Data Mapper, it is working fine and then I came to know new connector csvModule in MI. While converting I received below error.

"ERROR {SimpleMessageContext} - Error converting data : not a valid Json Array"

I added array in my json payload and then that error is not coming & payload properly converted, I think it's not a proper approach.

Can someone please help me with alternative approach to resolve this issue?

To resolve the error, temporarily I added array in my payload.

I am expecting JSON to CSV function of csvModule convert my payload properly.

Incoming JSON
{
"Name": "ABC",
"Age":25
}

Expected CSV
Name,Age
ABC,25

Comment: Please share the JSON payload and the format of the expected CSV

Comment: Added in question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a limitation of the CSV Module in the MI. If you are planning to use the CSV Module, the only option is to warp the JSON object with the `[]` brackets to convert it to an array.

As a workaround, you can use a Payload factory to convert the object to an array, leaving the input payload as it is.

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>[$1]</format>
    <args>
        <arg expression="$" evaluator="json"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<CSV.jsonToCsv/>
```

Comment: Thanks & Noted. As of now I am converting the payload like this only.